# Geometry Of Unitary Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, complex-numbers, soft-question

Ever since I first took Linear Algebra, I have over time realized how concepts like determinants, eigenvalues, diagonalization, orthogonal transformations and so on have very intuitive geometric interpretations, and so begun to fill in many gaps in my understanding of the subject (the course I took, just like most freshman-year courses I've taken, focused too much on pure computation and not enough on intuition / visualization, as do most course books on linear algebra that I've read).

Now, determinants are volumes (technically, multiplicative volume changes), diagonalization is just re-expressing the action of a matrix in terms of scalings of an eigenbase, and orthogonal transformations are norm- (and inner product-) preserving, and therefore fully characterized by compositions of rotations and reflections (and I still don't fully understand why the books start with $A^{-1}=A^T$ as the first definition of an orthogonal matrix…)…

…but what about *Unitary transformations / matrices*? They are also norm- (and inner product-) preserving, but may take complex-valued entries. How can I interpret this geometrically? For example, I know that the group SU(2) can be visualized as the 3-sphere (they are apparently diffeomorphic), but I cannot see the picture clearly in my head.

Comment: you don't fully understand $A^{-1} = A^T$ i.e. $A A^T = I$ probably because you focused too much on $\|.\|_2$ and not enough on $\langle.,.\rangle$ (the [inner product generating $\|.\|_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)) and the answer is exactly the same for unitary transformations, the inner product space being complex in that case

Comment: @user1952009 Ah, yes, I know that the inner product is preserved by unitary and orthogonal transformations (should have put that in the post), but what is the geometric picture in the complex case? What does a unitary transformation look like? Is it literally the same thing as an orthogonal transformation (rotations and reflections), but over a complex space instead of a real one?

Comment: yes, a $n \times n$ unitary matrix is a norm/inner-product preserving operator over a $n$ dimensional complex inner product space (or a $2n$ dimensional real inner product space) ${}{}{}$

Comment: Left multiplication by $i$ is a right-angle isoclinic rotation (of the underlying real space), and I think the unitary group is its stabilizer within the orthogonal group (of the underlying real space). Also, every rotation is a product of orthogonal plane rotations. Such a representation is unique if the angles are distinct - at the opposite end, when the angles are all the same, are isoclinic rotations. A unitary map interpreted as an orthogonal map has such a representation where each plane is an invariant one associated to the original multiplication-by-$i$ isoclinic rotation.